# How to restart recurring billing from 2checkout api?

Tags: payment-gateway, recurring-billing, 2checkout

In 2checkout if a user stopped recurring billing by api and than he/she want to restart that recurring billing, what is the procedure to do that? Can I restart a recurring billing from api? I found bellow information in their doc:

> After being stopped, recurring orders can be restarted by 2Checkout
>   staff for a variety of reasons, the most common being per buyer
>   request. In this most common case, a customer calls 2Checkout and
>   requests to restart billing on a recurring order.

But I want to restart recurring billing from api. Does [reauth](https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/api/sales/reauth) api can do that?